# How to replace system message text?

Tags: magento2, newsletter-subscriber

I want to replace the text of "The confirmation request has been sent", what is the best way to do it? create an module and overwrite this controller?
If yes, what is the correct path I should app/code or app/design?

thanks

```
/magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php
```

***NewAction.php***

```
    private function getSuccessMessage(int $status): Phrase
{
    if ($status === Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
        return __('The confirmation request has been sent.');
    }

    return __('Thank you for your subscription.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using translation files you can substitute what is output from `__($text)` functions. [Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html).

You could also use an [interceptor](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) to overwrite what is returned from this specific function if it did meet all the interceptor criteria -- unfortunately, [it doesn't](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#limitations).

Generally, overwriting a class should be a last-case scenario because it's easy for two pieces of functionality to desire the same original piece of code.

If it were me in this situation. I would likely use a translation file to keep my footprint low.

Comment: I will try to add this line to translation file, thanks

Comment: for using translation files, I just simply add this line to the csv file? --------- "The confirmation request has been sent.","Change to this message"

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html#translate_terms) it looks about right.